# Meteor: Using variable in child template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using template-level subscriptions, but I have some problems to use the results in a child template:

As I'm loading the template `example`, the template `exampleChild` will be displayed (just take this as an basic example - I know this doesn't make sense right now).

On creating the main template, the subscription is done and the data gets stored in a helper:

**Template**

```
<template name="example">
  {{> Template.dynamic template=switch}}
</template>

<template name="exampleChild">
  <h1>{{result}}</h1>
</template>
```

**Helper**

```
Template.example.helpers({
  switch: function() { return 'exampleChild'; },
  result: function() { return Template.instance().result(); },
});
```

**Event**

```
Template.example.onCreated(function() {
  var instance = this;

  instance.autorun(function () {
      var subscription = instance.subscribe('posts');
  });

  instance.result = function() { 
    return Collection.findOne({ _id: Session.get('id') });
  }
});
```

If I would put the `{{result}}` in the `example`-Template, everything is working. But I need to use the variable in the child template.

Comment: You make it look like the child template isn't contained within the parent template, and they're actually siblings. Please clarify if they have a sibling or parent/child relationship.

Comment: this is a child, just using Dynamic.template which isn't really "common" at this moment and probably confuse @Eleant.Scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
<template name="example">
{{#with result}}
      {{> Template.dynamic template=switch}}
{{/with}}    
</template>

<template name="exampleChild">
  <h1>{{this}}</h1>
</template>
```

[With doc](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/#with)

When doing that, I prefer wrap the data context result into an object, to have something proper on the child like:

```
Template.example.helpers({
  switch: function() { return 'exampleChild'; },
  data: function() { return {result: Template.instance().result()} },
});

   <template name="example">
    {{#with data}}
          {{> Template.dynamic template=switch}}
    {{/with}}    
    </template>

    <template name="exampleChild">
      <h1>{{result}}</h1>
    </template>
```

Hope it's help

Answer (score 0):

You could store the result in a session variable, and then add another helper to `exampleChild` that waits for the session variable.